# Find key contain specific key value pair in Puppet Hash

Tags: puppet

I am still a beginner in Puppet. So please bear with me. Let's assume i have this hash created in Puppet through some module

```
account = {
  user@desktop1 => { 
      owner => john, 
      type => ssh-rsa, 
      public => SomePublicKey
  }, 
  user@desktop2 => {
    owner => mary, 
    type => ssh-rsa, 
    public => SomePublicKey
  }, 
  user@desktop3 => {
    owner => john, 
    type => ssh-rsa, 
    public => SomePublicKey
  }, 
  user@desktop4 => {
    owner => matt, 
    type => ssh-rsa, 
    public => SomePublicKey
  }
}
```

How can i find find the key for specific key and value pair inside the hash? which in this case just for example i want to find all the key owned by `john`. So the expected result would be something like: 
`[user@desktop1, user@desktop3]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do your mean keys and values to be strings? If so, please edit to add quotes; if not, please explain. I question whether Puppet should be mentioned or the Puppet tags should be included, as this is just a question about a hash.

Comment: This question has mostly Puppet syntax for the hash, with the exception that the `account` variable needs to be denoted with a `$` to indicate variable. The syntax currently is not valid for Puppet or Ruby as far as I can tell. Like the others here I would request a clarification around whether this is Puppet or Ruby in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks about how to do this in Puppet, although, confusingly, the Hash is a Ruby Hash and the question also has a Ruby tag.

Anyway, this is how you do it in Puppet:

```
$account = {
  'user@desktop1' => {
    'owner' => 'john',
    'type'  => 'ssh-rsa',
    'public' => 'SomePublicKey',
  },
  'user@desktop2' => {
    'owner' => 'mary',
    'type'  => 'ssh-rsa',
    'public' => 'SomePublicKey',
  },
  'user@desktop3' => {
    'owner' => 'john',
    'type'  => 'ssh-rsa',
    'public' => 'SomePublicKey',
  },
  'user@desktop4' => {
    'owner' => 'matt',
    'type'  => 'ssh-rsa',
    'public' => 'SomePublicKey',
  }
}

$users = $account.filter |$k, $v| { $v['owner'] == 'john' }.keys

notice($users)
```

Puppet applying that leads to:

```
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): [user@desktop1, user@desktop3]
```

Comment: Thanks @alex-harvey. Works perfectly. Sorry for the confusion of putting in the ruby tag since i thought it could use some of the ruby function to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-select

```
account.select {|key, value| value['owner'] == 'john'}.keys
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
account.each_with_object([]) { |(k, v), a| a << k if v['owner'] == 'john'}
#=> ["user@desktop1", "user@desktop3"]
```

Supposing keys and values  to be `String`.